# Math domain error in Python

Tags: python

This program works for the value of the variable "n" set to 4, as it's the case in the following code:

```
from __future__ import division
from numpy import zeros
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numpy.linalg import linalg
import math


def getA(kappa):
    matrix = zeros((n, n), float)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            matrix[i][j] = 2*math.cos((2*math.pi/n)*(abs(j-i))*kappa)
    return matrix


def getF(csi, a):
    csiInv = linalg.inv(csi)
    valueF = np.dot(csiInv, a)
    valueF = np.dot(valueF, csiInv)
    valueF = np.dot(valueF, a)
    traceF = valueF.trace()
    return 0.5 * traceF


def getG(csi, f, a):
    csiInv = linalg.inv(csi)
    valueG = np.dot(csiInv, a)
    valueG = np.dot(valueG, csiInv)
    valueG = valueG / (2 * f)
    return valueG


def getE(g, k):
    #m = 10 ^ -6
    #kinv = linalg.inv(k + np.eye(k.shape[1])*m)
    kinv = linalg.inv(k)
    #kinv = linalg.pinv(k)
    ktrans = k.transpose()
    #ktransinv = linalg.pinv(ktrans)
    #ktransinv = linalg.inv(ktrans + np.eye(ktrans.shape[1])*m)
    ktransinv = linalg.inv(ktrans)
    e = np.dot(ktransinv,g)
    e = np.dot(e, kinv)
    return e

def getW(k, a, e):
    ktrans = k.transpose()
    w = np.dot(k, a)
    w = np.dot(w, ktrans)
    w = np.dot(w, e)
    valuew = w.trace()
    return valuew

def getV(csi, e, e2, k):
    v = np.dot(csi, k)
    v = np.dot(v, e)
    v = np.dot(v, k)
    v = np.dot(v, csi)
    v = np.dot(v,  k)
    v = np.dot(v, e2)
    v = np.dot(v, k)
    traceV = v.trace()
    return traceV


handle_2 = open("test.txt", "w")

n = 4


power_spectrum_k = np.zeros(n, float)
for i in range(n):
    power = math.exp(-(2*math.pi*i/n)*(2*math.pi*i/n))
    power_spectrum_k[i] = power

# ora posso chiamare l'anti-trasformata
inverse_transform = np.fft.ifft(power_spectrum_k)
print 'inverse_transform:', inverse_transform
CSI = zeros((n, n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        CSI[i][j] = inverse_transform[abs(i-j)]


betaArray = zeros(n, float)
WabArray = zeros((6, n), float)
correlation = zeros((6, 6), float)

list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

K = zeros((n, n), float)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1):
        i_shifted = i + 2
        j_shifted = j + 1
        print "###############################"
        print i_shifted
        print j

        component1 = ((3.0*70.0*70.0*0.3)/(2.0*300000.0*300000.0))
        component2 = ((j_shifted*(i_shifted-j_shifted))/(i_shifted))
        component3 = (1.0+(70.0/300000.0)*j_shifted)

        print component1
        print component2
        print component3

        K[i][j] = component1*component2*component3

#print 'DetK:', np.linalg.det(K)
print 'K:\n', K

counter = 0

for alpha in list:
    counter2 = 0
    Aa = getA(alpha)
    Faa = getF(CSI, Aa)
    Ga = getG(CSI, Faa, Aa)
    Ea = getE(Ga, K)
    #print 'Ea:', Ea
    V_alphaalpha = getV(CSI, Ea, Ea, K)
    for beta in xrange(n):
            Ab = getA(beta + 1)
            #print "Calling getW with K=", K, "\n Ab=", Ab, "\nEa=", Ea
            W_ab = getW(K, Ab, Ea)
            #print "\nGot W_ab=", W_ab
            betaArray[beta] = beta + 1
            WabArray[counter][beta] = W_ab
            output_string = " {0} {1} \n".format(str(beta + 1), str(W_ab))
            handle_2.write(output_string)
            Fbb = getF(CSI, Ab)
            Gb = getG(CSI, Fbb, Ab)
            Eb = getE(Gb, K)
    #print "Beta array"
    #print betaArray
    #print "Wab array"
    #print WabArray
    for gamma in list:
        Ac = getA(gamma)
        Fcc = getF(CSI, Ac)
        Gc = getG(CSI, Fcc, Ac)
        Ec = getE(Gc, K)
        V_alphagamma = getV(CSI, Ea, Ec, K)
        V_gammagamma = getV(CSI, Ec, Ec, K)
        C_alphagamma = V_alphagamma/(math.sqrt(V_alphaalpha * V_gammagamma))
        correlation[counter][counter2] = C_alphagamma
        counter2 = counter2 + 1
    counter = counter + 1


print 'correlation:\n', correlation
WabArray_all = []
betaArray_all = []
for b in range(0, len(WabArray), 1):
  for n in betaArray:
    betaArray_all.append(n)
  for n in WabArray[b]:
    WabArray_all.append(n)
```

Now, as soon as I get n = 5 and any other value bigger than 4, I receive the error:

```
line 148, in <module>
    C_alphagamma = V_alphagamma/(math.sqrt(V_alphaalpha * V_gammagamma))
ValueError: math domain error
```

which I interpret as a math error due to the fact that I performing the square root of a negative value. Nevertheless, I cannot understand where exactly is the error, in the sense that I cannot understand why changing from 4 to, say, 5 makes the difference. Has anyone any idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: You may want to start with an explanation of what your script is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try to reduce the size of the problem. Ask yourself: which one of V_alphaalpha and V_gammagamma has the wrong sign? Why? And then go backwards until you find the answer. I'm sorry, but in my experience, very few people are going to read all of your code in order to provide a concrete answer.

Comment: did you check possible maths problems such as negative square roots or maybe division by 0??

Answer (score 2):

`math.sqrt`  is unable to calculate the negative square root

```
>>> math.sqrt(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

If this is valid complex math, import `sqrt` from `cmath` instead:

```
>>> cmath.sqrt(-1)
1j
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say where the problem is without understanding the algorythm. You will have to do more investigations. IMHO, you should ty to dump the values to better understand the problem but only when thing goes wrong to avoid too much output. Something like :

```
try:
    C_alphagamma = V_alphagamma/(math.sqrt(V_alphaalpha * V_gammagamma))
except ValueError as e:
    print alpha, Aa, Faa, Ga, Ea, V_alphaalpha
    print gamma, Ac, Fcc, Gc, Ec, V_alphagamma, V_gammagamma
    raise e
```

This is only an idea and other values might be more pertinent